# Exibir dados com limite de tamanho do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Preciso exibir 20 registros por vez em uma lista HTML. Quando eu uso meu código, ele exibe todos os registros de uma vez.
A lista está dentro de um slide que é preenchido com mais dados, se houver.
A questão é que preciso dos registros de 20 em 20 para poder utilizar o slide, ao inves de deslizar para baixo para ver os demais registros.

```
<?php
include('bd.php');

$lin=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linke WHERE codigo='".$_GET['codigo']."'");
$linka=mysql_fetch_assoc($lin);

$sort=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorteio WHERE id='".$linka['id_estrangeiro']."'");
$sorteio=mysql_fetch_assoc($sort);

$sorteado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorteados WHERE id_usuario_sorteio='".$linka['id']."'");
$num_sorteados=mysql_num_rows($sorteado);

if($num_sorteados>0){
echo "<script>window.location='sucesso.php?codigo=".$_GET['codigo']."'</script>";
}

?>
```

sorteio.php

```
<div class="box32"> 
<div class="box4">
<div class="box5">
      <input name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Seu nome" type="text" />
      </div></div></div>
    <div class="box15">
       <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <ul>
    <?php
    $quantidade = $sorteio['quantidade'];
    for($row = 1; $row < $quantidade.length; $row++) {
    if($row<9){ $row = '0'.$row; }
    
    $sorteado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorteados WHERE id_sorteio='".$sorteio['id']."' and numero='".$row."'");
    $sorteados=mysql_num_rows($sorteado);
    
    if($sorteados>0){
    $classe='dezena_sorteada';
    }else{
    $classe='dezena inativa';
    }
    ?>
    <li><div class="<?php echo $classe; ?>" <?php if($sorteados==0){ ?>id="dezena" <?php } ?>><?php echo $row; ?></div></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
      
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
<ul>
       <?php
    $quantidade = $sorteio['quantidade'];
    for($row = 1; $row < $quantidade+1; $row++) {
    if($row<9){ $row = '0'.$row; }
    
    $sorteado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sorteados WHERE id_sorteio='".$sorteio['id']."' and numero='".$row."'");
    $sorteados=mysql_num_rows($sorteado);
    
    if($sorteados>0){
    $classe='dezena_sorteada';
    }else{
    $classe='dezena inativa';
    }
    ?>
    <li><div class="<?php echo $classe; ?>" <?php if($sorteados==0){ ?>id="dezena" <?php } ?>><?php echo $row; ?></div></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
      
    </div>
    
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
    <div class="box31">
    <div class="box5">
        <div class="box6" id="enviar_jogo">Enviar</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box5" id="erro_cadastro"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

tentei usar `SELECT * FROM sorteados WHERE id_sorteio='".$sorteio['id']."' and numero='".$row."' ORDER BY quantidade_numeros LIMIT 20"`  e nao retornou o esperado

Qualquer ajuda sera bem vinda!

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
tente usar a clausula FIRST.

```
SELECT FIRST 20 * FROM sorteados WHERE id_sorteio='".$sorteio['id']."' and numero='".$row."' ORDER BY quantidade_numeros"
```